# How can I calculate Average Position in Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am using Google Analytics API to PHP.
How can I add the average position to Adwords in my project, 
I thought in using the dimensions ga:adSlotPosition and ga:keyword, however when combined with metrics
ga:clicks, ga:impressions, ga:CPC, ga:CTR, ga:adCost does not work,
not be getting the values of average position for each keyword that shows the interface of adwords.

Example, Adwords displays the following:

KEYWORDS ... AVERAGE POSITION

- keyword1 **7.3**
- keyword2 **2.8**
- keyword3 **1.4**
- keyword4 **5.2**

The query I am doing is of this type:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($this->client);

$adwordsDimesion = "ga:keyword, ga:adSlotPosition";
$adwordsMetric = "ga:impressions"; I don´t know what is the correct metric
$optParams = array('dimensions' => $dimension);
$averagePosition = $service->data_ga->get($id,$initialDate,$finalDate, $adwordsMetric, adwordsDimesion, $optParams);
```

What metric should I use? or somebody know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: did you find any answer for this?